# WARN FPGrowth: Input data is not cached

Tags: python, pyspark, data-mining

I am trying to pyspark to get association rules. I have a group of transactions which are about 60000. Due to them problem with FPGrowth being able to train only 100 kb, I have 90 which is ok. However I am getting this warning :  **WARN FPGrowth: Input data is not cached.
pyspark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowthModel object at 0x7f1e600dd250.** I am confused now because I thought I did cache. how can I solve it

```
def getAssociationRules(transactionsGroup):
    ar = []
    cnt = 0
    for key, value in transactionsGroup.items():       
      for k, v in value.items():
        cnt += 1
        if cnt >= 90:
           break
        else:
           ar.append(v)  
   transactions = sc.parallelize(ar).cache()
   b = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.3, numPartitions=10)
   print b
```

Comment: Try other tools. MLlib does not have a good reputation, too much overhead. 60000 is tiny. Try ELKI or Weka (usually, ELKI is faster)